# PHP word generator

Tags: php, arrays, brute-force

i found this piece of code that generates words through a given string on stackoverflow, and it works, in my opinion, perfectly, there is only a problem... It uses arrays and as we all know arrays have a maximum dimension, so I ask you if there is a way to change this code in order not to use arrays but only "echo" or maybe an external .txt file or whatever you want that hasn't a memory limit

```
$letters = str_split("abc");

$combos = $letters;
$lastres = $letters;
for ($i = 1; $i < count($letters); $i++) {
    $newres = array();
    foreach ($lastres as $r) {
        foreach ($letters as $let) {
            $newres[] = $r . $let;

        }
    }

    foreach ($newres as $w) {
        $combos[] = $w;
    }

    $lastres = $newres;
}
foreach($combos as $comb){
    echo $comb."<br>";
}
```

I tried to think to a solution but can't get it :/ 
If you need, you can change the code how you want to, there are no problems.

Comment: Arrays have a maximum dimension?

Comment: What do you mean with  "and as we all know arrays have a maximum dimension," ... please explain .. better

Comment: arrays have no "maximum" dimension, other than the inherent limits of whatever PHP_MAX_INT is on your system. and by the time you hit an array that big, you'll have run out of memory anyways. In other words, you're wasting your time

Comment: maximum memory limit

Answer (score 1):

The only array that gets really large is `$combos`. If you don't need to save all the words you generate, just print the word out instead of adding it to this array. So simply change:

```
    $combos[] = $w;
```

to

```
    echo $w . '<br>';
```

But if you're generating so many words that it will cause a memory problem on the server, it will probably also take forever to send the results to the browser, and the browser may run out of memory trying to display the page.

Comment: I already tried it, but it says an array exceded the maximum limit of memory... I run it through windows terminal, so that it runs endlessly. Actually was doing this with a mysqli_query instead of "echo"

Comment: I see, `$newres` also grows very large.

Comment: Do you think there is any way to avoid that?

Comment: Instead of generating all the intermediate strings in `$newres` in order to get results of successive lengths, write a loop that generates all strings of length N. Then run that loop for successive values of N.

Comment: I don't feel like trying to figure this one out, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In one way you might way that arrays have a "maximum dimension". However, the only reason they have this maximum dimension or size is because PHP has a maximum memory limit that it can't exceed. The very same limit also applies to anything else PHP stores in memory, which can be strings, buffers, images etc. Because of this, simply converting the array to a string will not solve the limit problem.

Unless you have a word that is very long, or a very low memory limit that you can't change on your server, I'd suggest just sticking with the array, as it will work in 9 of out 10 cases.